# CMake Set Default Search Path?

Tags: cmake

I simply don't want to set an environment variable every time i need a library, let a lone the paths searched are not standardized at all (at least on windows). Generally the Find*.cmake doesn't specify any locations with association on windows.

Is there some way to make CMake search a specified directory (forcing bad configured Find*.cmake to search paths they otherwise wouldn't set at the system level)? Say i want it to search on "C:\" or just "/" on windows? That way i can just put all my libraries in "C:\".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to append paths to [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) in your project CMakeLists.txt, something like this:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/tmp/test" "/another/library/path")
```

According to the documentation, it will append "/lib" to the end of each path in the list and search for libraries there, but with some quick testing, it seems like cmake should find things alright if it's directly in a path you specify. For example, if I have `/tmp/test/libtest.so` and add the line above, I can find it like so:

```
find_library(libtest_LIBRARY test)
```

Running cmake should set the cache variable `libtest_LIBRARY` with the right path.

Comment: Didn't understand the 2nd line of your answer. But the first one solved my problem!

Comment: You can also pass the new path from the command line: `cmake -CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/tmp/test" ..