# CMake does not find ZyppCommon when configuring Zypper

Tags: cmake, zypper

I've already compiled and installed libzypp, but when I want to compile zypper then Cmake returns an error:

`CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (INCLUDE):
  INCLUDE could not find load file:
    ZyppCommon`

`CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (GENERATE_PACKAGING):
  Unknown CMake command "GENERATE_PACKAGING".`

`-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/origincode/zypper/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".`

**Environment**

My OS: Fedora 26

gcc version:7.1.1

cmake version:3.9.1

Comment: So, what is the content of `/home/origincode/zypper/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log` ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, that CMake does not find the file `ZyppCommon.cmake` which contains the definition of the macro `GENERATE_PACKAGING`. The file is part of libzypp (located in `cmake/modules/ZyppCommon.cmake`).

You have three options:

1. Install libzypp, then zypper's CMake will find the file.
2. You have to include the path to the file to the [CMake prefix path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25395880/2799037).
3. If you use some Suse / openSuse dritribution, installing libzypp-devel does install the required file.

If you have it installed, maybe you have to clear the CMake cache.